# xslt: the context item is absent in Function

Tags: xslt, saxon

my xml-pool is like

```
<POOL>
  <CUSTOMER>
    <GROUP_ID>
      2
    </GROUP_ID>
  </CUSTOMER>
</POOL>
```

I have a call for my Function, that looks like

```
<xsl:value-of select="nck:serviceNo(' ',' ')"/>
```

and my function is:

```
<xsl:function name="nck:serviceNo" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="spacer1" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="spacer2" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="num">
      1010<xsl:value-of select="$spacer1" />2020 3030<xsl:value-of select="$spacer2" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/POOL/CUSTOMER/GROUP_ID = 2" >
          10
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          0
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:sequence select="$num"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

My Error is:

> Type error at char 1 in expression in xsl:when/@test on line 31
> column 60 of test.xsl:   XPDY0002  Leading '/' selects
> nothing: the context item is absent Errors were reported during
> stylesheet compilation

I need a workarround for supplying the pool in the function, can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to pass in a node e.g. `<xsl:param name="group-id"/>` and pass in e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="nck:serviceNo(' ',' ', /POOL/CUSTOMER/GROUP_ID)"/>` where you then ckeck `<xsl:when test="$group-id = 2">` or declare a global param or variable e.g. `<xsl:param name="main-root" select="/"/>` and use e.g. `<xsl:when test="$main-root/POOL/CUSTOMER/GROUP_ID = 2">`.

Comment: I've used this before you answered, but I'm not really sophisticated. Thought there would be a more common soution.